# ArrayList need to be in response Attribute to access in JSTL of same JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

Why does an `ArrayList` need to be placed in a `request.setAttt(...)` when used in JSTL and not a normal string array when in the same jsp?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();  

     while (r.next()) {
               list.add(r.getString("stu_first_name"));
         }
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="names">
        <tr>
        <td>${names}</td><br/>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Change to a

```
String[] list = new String[x]
```

and you don't need

```
request.setAttribute("list", list);
```

for the

```
<c:forEach to work>
```

Have to use `${directive.list}` for it to work with out?

Comment: response doesn't have attributes. And the JSP EL always uses attributes. Whether it's an array or a List doesn't change anything. Try creating an as simple as possible JSP trying to access an array that is not set as an attribute, and you'll see that it doesn't work. If you manage to make it work, then post this complete simple example here. Also, it's JSTL, not JSLT.

Comment: Sorry was Request.. and Updated the JSTL -
Just strange a simple String can be used in a JSTL with out being set when an Obj would have to be.

Comment: No, that's not true. Try creating a reproducible example.

Comment: Humm I guess I missed that part of the code when I was working with it. You are correct thanks so they would need to be in the request for JSTL to access.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<%
        String[] colors = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
        //ArrayList<String> arrcolors = new ArrayList();
        //colors must be set to request for JSTL to access in code line.
        request.setAttribute("colors", colors);


    %>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>EL Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="tester" action="post" method="/dropentry">
            <select>
            <c:forEach items="${colors}" var="names"> 
                <option value="${names}">${names}</option>
             </c:forEach>   
        </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter James"
        </form>
```